# `date` command doesn't have an option for ISO-8601 week format input?

Tags: command-line, date

I occasionally use the `date` command to check the current or a future date's week number based on the ISO-8601 week-date calendar. To do this I simply use: `date +%V` to check the current ISO week number and `date -d "2021-12-25" +%V` to check the ISO week number of another date (Christmas day in this case).

However, it seems like it is not possible to do this in reverse. That is, get the date in "month-date" format given a date in "week number" format. For example, if I run `date -d "2021-W50-3"`, it generates an error saying the format is not supported. Why is it not and is there any way to input or store dates using this format?

Comment: May we assume that you are using GNU `date`? Did you try `date -d '2021-01-01 +51 weeks'`?

Comment: @Kusalananda, I'm not sure that a '+51+ will always do. January first does not even have to belong to the [first week of a given year](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61733557).

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Right you are.

Comment: It's unclear if you're asking "why does `date` not understand the special format date string that I've invented?" or "how do I calculate the dates of a particular week?"

Comment: @Kusalananda Sorry, I am not sure if it's the GNU `date`. I'm using the built-in `date` command in my distro (Fedora 33). I'm just curious as to why `date` doesn't support such standardized format.

Comment: @KoshoE What's the output you expect from `date -d "2021-W50-3"`?

Comment: `date --version` will probablty tell you that is is GNU date,

Comment: I checked and it looks like I'm using GNU date.

Regarding the output I'm expecting, I just thought that the date command would parse that kind of string without any problems as it still follows the ISO-8601 string format.

Comment: A calender would do the job.

Answer (score 5):

GNU `date`, with that non-standard `-d` option, only supports a limited set of date-time formats documented at `info date 'Date input formats'` (and online [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html)).

For a `date` implementation that supports more date formats including the one you're referring to, you can use the `date` implementation from `ast-open` (which can also take an input date with `-d` like GNU `date`).

That can also be the `date` builtin of the ksh93 shell if built as part of `ast-open` (rarely the case though), or instead of `date`, you can use its `printf` builtin (which is always included) and its `%T` specifier (which `bash` copied though without the time parsing part):

```
$ builtin date
$ date -d '2021-W50-3' +%F
2021-12-15
$ printf '%(%F)T\n' 2021-W50-3
2021-12-15
```

From the `bash` shell (or any other shell), you can always do it as:

```
$ ksh93 -c '"${@:0}"' printf '%(%F)T\n' 2021-W50-3
2021-12-15
```

though note that depending on the system, ksh93 may be known as `ksh`, `ksh2020` (or even `sh` like on Solaris 11+; though it's also known as `ksh` there), or not at all, as ksh93, like bash or zsh is not installed by default on all systems.

Note that while [standard `strftime()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/strftime.html) can produce dates in that standard format with the `%G-%V-%u` specification, the corresponding standard function to *parse* timestamps ([`strptime()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/strptime.html)) doesn't support `%G` nor `%V` (nor does [standard UNIX `getdate()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/getdate.html)).

GNU `strptime()` is currently documented to understand them (as an extension over the standard) but ignore them (see [`info libc strptime`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Low_002dLevel-Time-String-Parsing.html#index-strptime)). [FreeBSD `strptime()`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strptime&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD%2013.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) is documented to support the same directives as `strftime()` but in my test on FreeBSD 12.2 (using `zsh`'s `strftime -r` builtin), it doesn't seem to work there.

POSIX, GNU and freebsd `strptime()` do support `%W` though.

- `zsh`:

  ```
  $ strftime -rs t %Y-W%W-%u 2021-W50-3 && strftime %F $t
  2021-12-15
  ```
- `busybox`:

  ```
  $ busybox date -D %Y-W%W-%u -d 2021-W50-3 +%F
  2021-12-15
  ```

`%Y-%W` is not the same as `%G-%V` though, it just happens to coincide in this case. `%W` on the first of January is 00 unless that's a Monday in which case it's 01. Whilst `%V` (the ISO week number) is either the first week of the year (01) or the last week of the previous year (52 or 53) depending on whether that week has more days in the previous or current year.

Comment: So it is a limit imposed by `strptime()` in C?

Comment: @KoshoE, no, the POSIX or C standard don't prohibit `strptime()` implementations from supporting parsing those ISO week numbers. [Standard `date`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/date.html) has no date parsing other than (optionally) with *one* specific format and only to set the date, and the GNU implementation doesn't use `strptime()`. It's more likely that no body bothered because nobody asked for it.

Comment: Sorry for asking further clarification. So POSIX's `strptime()` and GNU's `date` implement date parsing differently, if I understand it correctly? With that, both of them doesn't have a standard support for parsing dates in the ISO-8601 format?

Comment: I gave a link to the [POSIX `date` specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/date.html). POSIX `date` can't be used for parsing dates, that's not what POSIX date does. There's no utility in the POSIX toolchest to parse dates. `-d` is an extension of the GNU implementation of `date`. `-d` is used for something completely different on BSDs for instance. busybox date and ast-open date did add a `-d` with a similar semantic as GNU date but with a different implementation and different supported formats.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to get the precise ISO week date (including the flip into previous or next year) by using two executions of `date`: one to calibrate a known day (I chose 01-June), and one to adjust by the number of days for the ISO week/day difference. This is unaffected by leap years -- that's the whole point of using ISO weeks instead of months.

This is a function that converts 2021-W50-3 format to 2021-12-15, with tests that show the year roll-over.

```
#! /bin/bash

isoDate () {

    declare -a dR   #.. Required date
    declare -a dC   #.. Calibration date.
    printf 1>&2 '\nAsked %s\n' "${1}"   #debug
    IFS='-' read -a dR <<<"${1}"
    IFS='-' read -a dC <<<"$( date -d "${dR[0]}-06-01" '+%G-W%V-%u' )"
    dR[1]=${dR[1]#W}; dR[1]=${dR[1]#0}
    dC[1]=${dC[1]#W}; dC[1]=${dC[1]#0}
    declare Adj=$(( 7 * (${dR[1]} - ${dC[1]}) + ${dR[2]} - ${dC[2]} ))
    date -d "${dR[0]}-06-01 + ${Adj} days" '+%Y-%m-%d'
}

    Ymd=$( isoDate '2021-W50-3' )
    printf 'Found %s\n' "${Ymd}"
    date -d "${Ymd}" '+Check %G-W%V-%u'

    Ymd=$( isoDate '2020-W01-1' )
    printf 'Found %s\n' "${Ymd}"
    date -d "${Ymd}" '+Check %G-W%V-%u'

    Ymd=$( isoDate '2011-W52-7' )
    printf 'Found %s\n' "${Ymd}"
    date -d "${Ymd}" '+Check %G-W%V-%u'
```

And the results:

```
$ ./isoDate

Asked 2021-W50-3
Found 2021-12-15
Check 2021-W50-3

Asked 2020-W01-1
Found 2019-12-30
Check 2020-W01-1

Asked 2011-W52-7
Found 2012-01-01
Check 2011-W52-7
$
```

Comment: Date-time computation is one of the trickier programming domains, has this code been published  (and thus reviewed) elsewhere?

Comment: @Jasen  Fresh from my own imagination, guided by bitter experience. The `declare` stuff was to ensure all variables are local and don't mess with the rest of the user code. I was also mildly surprised that `date -d` is good with `2020-06-01 + -154 days`. Tested on GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1), Linux Mint 19.3, but I cannot vouch for portability. I should possibly validate the original `2021-W50-3` format, but that's really the caller's problem.

Comment: This is a very interesting approach. However, this looks somewhat *hacky* (if you know what I mean).

Comment: @KoshoE  I would be glad to see a better (tested) solution. The intent of providing a shell function is that you can save it in a script or .bashrc file, so you don't have to look at it again. My first idea was to call `date -d ymd '+ISO-out'` for every day in the year and grep the required ISO, so this is 99% less hacky than that concept. Happily, I saw the light after about 90 seconds: exploit the arithmetic regularity of 7-day weeks.